# Ask questions about location

Tags: grammar, sentence-structure, questions

To ask where the location of a state is as part of a larger area, we can ask

> Where in the US is Montana?
>   Montana is in the North of the US.

What about a question on the locations of two countries for example?
I mean a question the answer to which is:
"Canada is north of the US."

Something like:

> Where of the US is Canada located?
>   It is North of the US.

The form sounds kind of strange to me, though. Is there a better way to ask that question?

Comment: *Where of* isn't idiomatic English. "Where is Canada relative to the US?"

Answer (score 3):

> Where in the US is Montana?
>   Montana is in the northern part of the US.

It is better to use "part" because you are referring to an area of land. "north" in your example is just a direction.

> Where *in relation to* the US is Canada located?
>   It is north of the US.

"relation" is used to set the reference point (the US).

Also, directions like *north* are not capitalized unless part of a proper name (Ex. North America).